# Como adicionar parametros AND em consulta EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Minha `view` envia 5 parametros `bool`

Com base nestes parametros como eu adiciono `where and` em minha query?

Meu código é

```
var query = db.Registros.AsQueryable();

if(model Paramter1) 
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.Kind == MyEnum.Value1);
}

if(model Paramter2) 
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.Kind == MyEnum.Value2);
}
```

Mas não funciona

Eu preciso que seja adicionado `AND` a cada condição aceita

Algo como isso:

```
SELECT * FROM RECORDS
if(model.Paramter1) {
 SELECT* FROM RECORDS WHERE KIND = 1
}
if(model.Paramter2) {
 SELECT* FROM RECORDS WHERE KIND = 1 AND KIND = 2
}
```

Comment: Fala cara, aqui é o SOpt, pode fazer em português as perguntas

Comment: @Tmilitino nem tinha reparado kkkk Mas já traduzi :)

Comment: Isto está correto: `...WHERE KIND = 1 AND KIND = 2` ? Não sei se estou esquecendo de algo mas quando diz `Kind = 1 AND Kind = 2` nunca vai retornar resultados, não? Não quis dizer `Kind = 1 OR Kind = 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar PredicateBuilder

1 - Crie a seguinte classe:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

2 - Use, agora, da seguinte forma:

```
var query = db.Registros.AsQueryable();
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SuaEntidade>();
if(model Paramter1) 
{
   predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Kind == MyEnum.Value2);
}
if(model Paramter2) 
{
   predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Kind == MyEnum.Value3);
}
var resultado = query.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

query.Where(x => x.Kind == MyEnum.Value1 || x.Kind == MyEnum.Value1 )

|| pra OR e se fosse AND seria &&

tenta ai e me fala

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]